# OPOS CheckHealth returns OPOS_EX_NOINPUT (10007), OPOS for .NET

Tags: c#, opos

I've installed the latest EPSON OPOS ADK Version2.80E UPOS 1.14 and OPOS Common Control Objects 1.14.001 and OPOS for .NET assemblies on two machines with Windows 10 and Windows 7 to be able to communicate with Epson Slip Printer TM-U590.

I've also setup the configuration in registry like COM port, BaudRate etc.

I'm using OPOS for .NET assemblies to communicate with the printer. On Windows 10 everything works but on Windows 7 CheckHealth method returns

`OPOS_E_ILLEGAL (10007, OPOS_EX_NOINPUT)`.

POS Printer Check Healt utility from EPSON OPOS ADK returns 
`OPOS_E_ILLEGAL, 10007 (0x00002717)`. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Details and countermeasures are described in OPOS ADK manual / application development guide.
Please deal accordingly.

In addition, are you calling the CheckHealth method after setting the paper?
If the parameter is External or Interactive, I think that paper must be loaded in order to actually print.

If you do not solve the problem by checking them, please contact EPSON support.

Comment: Where can I find OPOS ADK manual / application development guide?

Comment: It should be installed at the same time when OPOS ADK is installed. If not, you can download from here. [OPOS ADK - Slip Printer](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&pcat=6&scat=38)

Comment: I've read the manual and all communication settings are correct. Paper is loaded during calling the CheckHealth method. Strange thing is that CheckHealth returns OPOS_EX_NOINPUT error in case the com port is not set correctly.

Comment: @user2250152, If you still have problems or questions, please contact EPSON support.

Comment: It was issue with USB cable. I changed the cable for different one 5x times and at the end the printer works fine.